# Rails connects to MySQL from WEBrick but not from Passenger

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger

I just created a new Rails 4 app with MySql as follows:

```
rails new mysqltest -d mysql
```

And modified the database.yml with the right credentials.

I generated a sample contoller and updated the routes for root route.

When I start using WEBrick in production,

```
rails s -e production
```

The site works. I see the index page.

When I start using Passenger without 3000 port, I see the following error:

```
database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

Passsenger is running in Production environment.

My database.yml

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: sample
  pool: 5
  username: sample
  password: sample
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: sample
  pool: 5
  username: sample
  password: sample
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: sample
  pool: 5
  username: sample
  password: sample
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: It seems you haven't configured your database for production environment. Could you share your database.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case I used in database.yml file and the apache config file were different.

Both should be same. eg. `production`.

In apache config, I gave as `Production`. After changing it to `production` it worked.

Source - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/Kr-R0gSw6i8

Comment: Saved me but also check the encoding on production configuration. I forgot an f :P

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your local production database?

```
rake db:create:all
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Is your database.yml file setup properly to use a production database?

Do you have a mysql gem in your gem file.

Common problems.

Comment: rake tasks are not required since I have created the database manually. database.yml is setup correctly (because it works in WEBrick). I have mysql2 in my Gemfile.